# Баг с python kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, kivy

На телефоне начало появляться какое-то странное изображение,хотя вместо него должны быть цифры.Из-за чего это?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorPicker
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
import random
Config.set('graphics','resizable','1')
Config.set('graphics','width','1200')




r,g,b,a = 0,0,0,1
pos_vari = [0.1,0,2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5]
pos_varig = [1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]

rp,gp,bp = 0,0,0
rp_d,gp_d,bp_d = 0,0,0
class ColorApp(App):
    background_normal = StringProperty( 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button')




    def changeColor(self, instance):
        global r,g,b,a,pos_vari,pos_varig,rp,gp,bp,rp_d,gp_d,bp_d

        if rp == 0 and gp == 0 and bp == 0 and rp_d == 0 and gp_d == 0 and bp_d == 0:

            r = random.choice(pos_vari)
            g = random.choice(pos_vari)
            b = random.choice(pos_vari)
            a = random.choice(pos_varig)

            instance.background_color = [r,g,b,a]

            mix = "RGB:"+" "+ str( round( float(r)* 88 ) )[0:-2]+" | " + str( round( float(g)* 88 ) )[0:-2] + " | " + str( round( float(b)* 88 ) )[0:-2]
            instance.font_size = 120
            instance.text = mix



        if rp == 1:
            if r + 0.1 <= 3:

                r = r +0.1
                instance.background_color = [r,g,b,a]
                mix = "RGB:"+" "+ str( round( float(r)* 88 ) )[0:-2]+" | " + str( round( float(g)* 88 ) )[0:-2] + " | " + str( round( float(b)* 88 ) )[0:-2]
                instance.font_size = 120
                instance.text = mix
                if r > 2.4 and g > 2.4 and b > 2.4:
                    instance.text = '[color=#000000]' + instance.text + '[/color]'
        if gp == 1:
            if g + 0.1 <= 3:
                g = g +0.1
                instance.background_color = [r,g,b,a]
                mix = "RGB:"+" "+ str( round( float(r)* 88 ) )[0:-2]+" | " + str( round( float(g)* 88 ) )[0:-2] + " | " + str( round( float(b)* 88 ) )[0:-2]
                instance.font_size = 120
                instance.text = mix
                if r > 2.4 and g > 2.4 and b > 2.4:
                    instance.text = '[color=#000000]' + instance.text + '[/color]'
        if bp == 1:
            if b + 0.1 <= 3:
                b = b +0.1
                instance.background_color = [r,g,b,a]
                mix = "RGB:"+" "+ str( round( float(r)* 88 ) )[0:-2]+" | " + str( round( float(g)* 88 ) )[0:-2] + " | " + str( round( float(b)* 88 ) )[0:-2]
                instance.font_size = 120
                instance.text = mix
                if r > 2.4 and g > 2.4 and b > 2.4:
                    instance.text = '[color=#000000]' + instance.text + '[/color]'
        if rp_d == 1:
            if r - 0.1 > 0:
                r = r -0.1
                instance.background_color = [r,g,b,a]
                mix = "RGB:"+" "+ str( round( float(r)* 88 ) )[0:-2]+" | " + str( round( float(g)* 88 ) )[0:-2] + " | " + str( round( float(b)* 88 ) )[0:-2]
                instance.font_size = 120
                instance.text = mix
                if r > 2.4 and g > 2.4 and b > 2.4:
                    instance.text = '[color=#000000]' + instance.text + '[/color]'

        if gp_d == 1:

            if g - 0.1 > 0:

                g = g -0.1
                instance.background_color = [r,g,b,a]
                mix = "RGB:"+" "+ str( round( float(r)* 88 ) )[0:-2]+" | " + str( round( float(g)* 88 ) )[0:-2] + " | " + str( round( float(b)* 88 ) )[0:-2]
                instance.font_size = 120
                instance.text = mix
                if r > 2.4 and g > 2.4 and b > 2.4:
                    instance.text = '[color=#000000]' + instance.text + '[/color]'


        if bp_d == 1:
            if b - 0.1 > 0:
                b = b -0.1
                instance.background_color = [r,g,b,a]
                mix = "RGB:"+" "+ str( round( float(r)* 88 ) )[0:-2]+" | " + str( round( float(g)* 88 ) )[0:-2] + " | " + str( round( float(b)* 88 ) )[0:-2]
                instance.font_size = 120
                instance.text = mix
                if r > 2.4 and g > 2.4 and b > 2.4:
                    instance.text = '[color=#000000]' + instance.text + '[/color]'



    def sw_r_c(self,instance, value):
        if value == True:
            global rp,gp,bp
            rp = 1
            return self.changeColor
        else:
            rp = 0

    def sw_g_c(self,instance, value):
        if value == True:
            global rp,gp,bp
            gp = 1
            return self.changeColor
        else:
            gp = 0

    def sw_b_c(self,instance, value):
        if value == True:
            global rp,gp,bp
            bp = 1
            return self.changeColor
        else:
            bp = 0



    def sw_r_c_d(self,instance, value):
        if value == True:
            global rp_d,gp_d,bp_d
            rp_d = 1
            return self.changeColor
        else:
            rp_d = 0


    def sw_g_c_d(self,instance, value):
        if value == True:
            global rp_d,gp_d,bp_d
            gp_d = 1
            return self.changeColor
        else:
            gp_d = 0

    def sw_b_c_d(self,instance, value):
        if value == True:
            global rp_d,gp_d,bp_d
            bp_d = 1
            return self.changeColor
        else:
            bp_d = 0


    def build(self):

        bl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        colorButton = Button(text='[color=#000000]' + 'ColorS' +'[/color]'+'\nSwipe right to more tools',
        font_size=50,
        background_color=[1,1,1,1],
        on_press=self.changeColor,
        background_down= self.background_normal,
        markup=True)

        bl.add_widget(colorButton)
        bl_st = GridLayout(size_hint=(1,0.15),cols=6,spacing=0)

        lab_up_r = Label(text='+R Mode',font_size=20)
        lab_up_g = Label(text='+G Mode',font_size=20)
        lab_up_b = Label(text='+B Mode',font_size=20)

        lab_dn_r = Label(text='-R Mode',font_size=20)
        lab_dn_g = Label(text='-G Mode',font_size=20)
        lab_dn_b = Label(text='-B Mode',font_size=20)

        sw_r = Switch(active=False)
        sw_r.bind(active=self.sw_r_c)

        sw_g = Switch(active=False)
        sw_g.bind(active=self.sw_g_c)

        sw_b = Switch(active=False)
        sw_b.bind(active=self.sw_b_c)



        sw_r_d = Switch(active=False)
        sw_r_d.bind(active=self.sw_r_c_d)

        sw_g_d = Switch(active=False)
        sw_g_d.bind(active=self.sw_g_c_d)

        sw_b_d = Switch(active=False)
        sw_b_d.bind(active=self.sw_b_c_d)


        bl_st.add_widget(lab_up_r)
        bl_st.add_widget(lab_up_g)
        bl_st.add_widget(lab_up_b)

        bl_st.add_widget(lab_dn_r)
        bl_st.add_widget(lab_dn_g)
        bl_st.add_widget(lab_dn_b)

        bl_st.add_widget(sw_r)
        bl_st.add_widget(sw_g)
        bl_st.add_widget(sw_b)

        bl_st.add_widget(sw_r_d)
        bl_st.add_widget(sw_g_d)
        bl_st.add_widget(sw_b_d)

        bl.add_widget(bl_st)
        clr_picker = ColorPicker()



        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')
        carousel.add_widget(bl)
        carousel.add_widget(clr_picker)
        return carousel

ColorApp().run()
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что  Вы уже [задали его в прошлый раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823478/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-kivy-python)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Непонятное изображение Kivy Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823478/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-kivy-python)

Comment: Покажите код вашего 'бага'...

Comment: @Xyanight Добавил.На ПК все работает,а вот на телефоне начинает появляться та штука

Answer (score 0):

Нашел выход.У кого также не будет работать на телефоне,хотя на ПК работает,нужно просто поставить markup=False везде где только можно(не знаю как это влияет на все это,но работает) или сменить компилятор.